# [python]Apontar para o próximo maior valor da sublista

Tags: python, lista, lista-encadeada

Foi pedido pelo professor para ordenar a sublista por bubblesort, então pegar o último elemento de cada lista e adicionar o valor mais alto a uma lista auxiliar, a fim de obter uma lista ordenada final, então estou tentando encontrar o próximo valor máximo de listas aninhadas já classificadas por bubblesort, até que a lista seja classificada.

eu tenho a lista [[1, 7, 9], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 8], [0]]

E gostaria que minha saída me desse a lista ordenada em outra lista.

exemplo da operação:

max_values = [9,6,8,0] #Maiores valores de cada sublista

output = [9] #resultdo final

max_values = [7,6,8,0] #Maiores valores de cada sublista(sem o valor 9-já ordenado)

output =[8,9] #resultado

max_values = [7,6,3,0] #Maiores valores de cada sublista(sem o valor 8 e 9-já ordenado)

output = [7,8,9] #resultado

max_values = [1,6,3,0]

...

max_values=[0]

até que o vetor fique totalmente ordenado

output=[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

veja a imagem como exemplo

[image: exemplo da execução]

A resposta do meu professor foi:" Você não precisa de fato remover o elemento, basta apontar para o próximo maior, certo? Se você guardar um índice para cada sublista indicando qual o maior elemento a ser analisado você resolve isso em tempo constante. Quando você descobre o maior elemento, basta decrementar o índice correspondente.
"

Porém eu nao to conseguindo implementar tal código. O unico avanço que eu tive foi esse:

```
def bubbleSort(array): #tempo O(n^2)
    n = len(array)-1
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n-i):
            if array[j] > array[j+1]:
                array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]
            else:
                continue
    return array

def ordena_lista(output): 
    for sublista in output:
        bubbleSort(sublista)

def maior_valor_lista(output):
    return list(el[-1] for el in output)

b = list(random.sample(range(10), 10))
n= m.floor(m.sqrt(len(b)))
output=list([b[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(b), n)])
ordena_lista(output)
while output:
        valores_maximo = maior_valor_lista(output)
        var = max(valores_maximo, key=int)
        final = [var] + final
```

Answer (score -2):

Usando a sua geração de array aleatória:

```
import random
import math as m

b = list(random.sample(range(10), 10))
n = m.floor(m.sqrt(len(b)))
output = list([b[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(b), n)])
```

A primeira coisa foi declarar 2 arrays para usar como auxiliares, um pra guardar os valores mais altos das sublistas(max_values) e outro pra guardar o resultado final(result)

```
max_values = []
result = []
```

Também criei uma função para remover do array chave(output) um valor x

```
def removeValueFromSubArray(array, value):
  for i in array:
    if i.count(value) > 0:
      i.remove(value)

    if len(i) == 0:
      array.remove(i)
```

Daí a lógica principal:

Ele vai executar o for enquanto o tamanho do arra chave(output) for maior do que 0, ou seja, enquanto ainda houver valores nele.

Ele vai entrar em cada sublista, ordenar do menor para o maior e pegar o maior valor dessa sublista e jogar na lista max_values. Depois, ele vai ordenar a lista max_values, pegar o maior valor e jogar no result.

Depois que o valor já estiver no result, ele remove esse valor do array chave(output) e limpa o array auxiliar(max_values).

No final ele ordena o array de saída(result) do menor para o maior e printa na tela.

```
while len(output) > 0:
  for i in output:
    i.sort()

    if len(i) > 0:
      max_values.append(i[-1])

    max_values.sort()

  result.append(max_values[-1])
  removeValueFromSubArray(output, max_values[-1])

  max_values.clear()

result.sort()

print(result)
```

Se tiver alguma dúvida sobre algum trecho do código pode me perguntar aqui nos comentários

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Então... no caso eu não preciso ordena a lista(result) no caso eu preciso pegar o maior valor de cada sublista, adicionar numa lista final, e depois decrementar do indice que eu retirei o maior valor dentre as sublistas, eu nao posso remover o elemento pq gasta tempo desnecessário, se voce reparar na imagem, dá para reparar que eu coleto o 9 da sublista e adiciono na lista final e ando com o indice para o próximo maior valor que é o 7.